# ReactJS Having trouble setState on UseEffect when dependencies change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to setState on dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.speed when users input both time and round. It's working fine if not 'HOLDING' a key when I change time or round value,
but when I HOLD backspace or any other keys on <Input {time,round} /> it's causing an infinite loop. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
const [dischargeMeasureInput, setDischargeMeasureInput] = useState({
        discOperatId: null, discMeasureId: null,
        orderNo: '1', depthPoint: '3', depth: null, distant: null,
        point2D: { surfaceD: null, time: null, round: null, speed: null }
})    

useEffect(() => {
        if (dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.time && dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.round) {
               axios()...
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.data) {
                        setDischargeMeasureInput({ ...dischargeMeasureInput, point2D: { ...dischargeMeasureInput.point2D, speed: res.data.velocityPoint1 } })
                    }
                    else {
                        setDischargeMeasureInput({ ...dischargeMeasureInput, point2D: { ...dischargeMeasureInput.point2D, speed: null } })
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        }

}, [dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.time, dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.round])

//child Component
<Input value={props.dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.time}
       onChange={(e) => props.setDischargeMeasureInput({ ...props.dischargeMeasureInput, point2D: { ...props.dischargeMeasureInput.point2D, time: e.target.value } })}/>
                
<Input value={props.dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.round}
       onChange={(e) => props.setDischargeMeasureInput({ ...props.dischargeMeasureInput, point2D: { ...props.dischargeMeasureInput.point2D, round: e.target.value } })} />
                
<Input value={props.dischargeMeasureInput.point2D.speed}
       onChange={(e) => props.setDischargeMeasureInput({ ...props.dischargeMeasureInput, point2D: { ...props.dischargeMeasureInput.point2D, speed: e.target.value } })} />
```

Here's a short .gif

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, it seems there's a race condition.
I just have to add bool flag before setState.
This link help me out
https://medium.com/hackernoon/avoiding-race-conditions-when-fetching-data-with-react-hooks-220d6fd0f663

```
useEffect(() => {
    let canceled = false
    
    if(!canceled)
     setDischargeMeasureInput({ ...dischargeMeasureInput, point2D: { ...dischargeMeasureInput.point2D, speed: res.data.velocityPoint1 } })
    }
    
    //and cleanup function
    return () => (canceled = true)
})
```